# How to find matrix $K$ such that $KM=0$ with $M$ full-rank?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I have a full-rank matrix $M$ of size $(2n,n)$ and I try to find a non-zero matrix $K$ of size $(n,2n)$ such that the product of $K$ and $M$ results in the zero matrix, i.e., $KM=0$.
The null-space of $M$ is trivial since it's a full-rank matrix, so I currently see no way in using the null space of $M$ to find $K$. Are there suggestions to my problem?

Comment: @Damien No, the null space really is trivial. But its image is a subspace of dimension $n$ within the space of dimension $2n$. So we need the null space of $K$ to contain the image of $M$.

Comment: Note that this could be interpreted (and dealt with) in two equivalent ways. If your vectors are *column vectors*, then $M$ represents a linear map $\mathbb{R}^{n} \to \mathbb{R}^{2n}$ with image of dimension $n$. So, as suggested by @aschepler, you should find a matrix $K$ (which will represent a linear map $\mathbb{R}^{2n} \to \mathbb{R}^{n}$) whose kernel contains the image of $M$. (You may even have the image of $M$ coincide with the kernel of $K$.) 1/2

Comment: If your vectors are *row vectors*, then $M$ represent a linear map $\mathbb{R}^{2n} \to \mathbb{R}^{n}$ whose kernel has dimension $n$. And then you have to find a matrix $K$ (which this time represents a linear map $\mathbb{R}^{n} \to \mathbb{R}^{2n}$) whose image is contained in the kernel of $M$. 2/2

Comment: Above comments are excellent.

Comment: @Andreas Caranti matrix of a linear map from $\mathbb{R}^{2n} \to \mathbb{R}^{n}$ is a matix of order $n\times 2n$ not $2n\times n$.

Comment: Note that $KM = 0$ if and only if $M^TK^T = 0$, so it is the nullspace of $M^T$ that concerns you here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's perhaps easier if you consider a matrix $N$ of shape $n\times 2n$ with rank $n$. Its null space has dimension $n$, and so you can surely find a vector $v\ne0$ such that $Nv=0$.

Now take $L=[v\ v\ v\ \dots\ v]$ with $n$ columns and $NL=0$.

OK, now consider $N=M^T$ and you see that $K=L^T$ fits the bill.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Problem solved. :)

Answer (score 1):

I assume we are working over the real numbers $\mathbb{R}$.

Let $m_1, m_2, \dots, m_n$ be the columns of $M$ and let $e_1,e_2,\dots, e_{2n}$ be the standard basis of the column space.

Apply the Gram-Schmidt process to the sequence $m_1, m_2, \dots, m_n,e_1,e_2,\dots, e_{2n}$ to extract an orthonormal basis $f_1,\dots,f_{2n}$.

For $K$ take the matrix whose rows are $f_{n+1}^T,\dots,f_{2n}^T$.

[I actually think this is rather horrid!]

Comment: Thanks a lot! For me, egregs answer is the easiest one to implement. That's why I accepted that one.

Comment: Yes, if all you need is a $K\ne 0$ that's definitely the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

$T : F^{n} \to F^{2n}$  be a linear map with  $dim(R(T)) =n$

Define a linear map $S:F^{2n} \to F^{n}$ such that $R(T) \subseteq Ker(S) $

Assume that such linear map $S$ exists.

Then

$S\circ T: F^{n} \to F^{n}$

Claim: $S\circ T=0 $

Choose, $v\in F^{n}$

\begin{align} S\circ T(v) &=S( T(v))=S(0)=0 \end{align}

Since, $T(v) \in Ker(S) \implies S(T(v)) =0$

Now, we prove the existence of such linear map $S$

Define,  $ S_1 : F^{2n}\to F^{2n}/{R(T)} $ by $$S_1(v) =v+R(T) $$

Then, $Ker(S_1) =R(T) $

Now, $F^{2n}/{R(T)}\cong F^n$

Let, $S_2 : F^{2n}/{R(T)}\to F^n$ be an isomorphism, then

$S_2\circ S_1=S$ be the required linear map satisfying   $ST=0$.

Comment: Please inform me if there is anything wrong.